# ember js get multiple checkbox value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My templates:

```
<form name="spam_list" {{action 'spamDecide' on='submit'}}>
    {{#each model as |spam|}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{input type="checkbox" name="trash[]" checked=spam.isCheck}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}                       
<button {{action 'checkAll'}}>Check All</button>
</form>
```

My routes:

```
model(){
        // return 10 spams
    },
```

My controller:

```
actions:{
        spamDecide: function(model){
             var isCheck = model.getEach('isCheck');
             console.log(isCheck);
        },

        checkAll: function(model){
            var model = this.get('model');
            model.setEach('isCheck',true);
        },
    }
```

Currently action checkAll is work fine, set all checkbox into checked. My question is how can I know which checkbox is checked when I manually check them.
For example I set checkbox 1 5 7 is checked, then get the equivalent spam.id with each check?

Comment: `{{input type="checkbox" name="trash[]" checked=spam.isCheck on-change=(action (mut spam.isCheck) checked)}}`  this will automatically bind `spam.isCheck` property to corresponding checkbox

Comment: @kumkanillam then how can I take that property out?

Comment: Mut helper will update model properties so you can iterate using any of the array enumerables method. Like locks mentioned you can use `model.filterBy('isCheck')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read correctly, what you're looking for is to get a list of checked objects in `spamDecide`. You should be able to do it along these lines:

```
actions:{
  spamDecide: function(model){
    var checkedModels = model.filterBy('isCheck');
    console.log(checkedModels);
  },
}
```

While [`Array#getEach` (alias for `Array#mapEach`)](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_getEach) returns an array of each item's `isCheck` property, [`filterBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filterBy) returns the items that have the `isCheck` property set to true.

If you want the ids you can then do `checkedModels.mapBy('id')`.

I hope that was helpful!